# How do I download FontAwesome Pro without NPM?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome-5

As part of the build script for my project I need to download FontAwesome Pro, but NPM or YARN is not available to me. How can I download FontAwesome Pro from the CLI without a package manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect your npm Package Token from your FontAwesome Account page, then you can use that token as the Bearer value for the Authorization Header when downloading from FontAwesome's npm Pro registry.

For example:

```
curl -O -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your token here>' https://npm.fontawesome.com/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/-/fontawesome-pro-5.6.3.tgz
```

Will download FontAwesome Pro 5.6.3